# Using simplest vscode devcontainers setup, cannot write files from inside container

Tags: linux, docker, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I am using [vscode devcontainers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers).

My enviroment, setup, and execution is as follows:

`devcontainer@0.35.0`,`Docker version 23.0.4, build f480fb1`,`Docker Compose version v2.17.2`,`ubuntu 20`

```
.devcontainer
  |-  .devcontainer.json
  |-  Dockerfile
```

.devcontainer.json:

```
{
    "name": "Node.js",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
    },
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
        "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
            "bash": {
                "path": "/bin/bash",
                "icon": "terminal-bash",
            },
        },
    },
    "extensions": [
        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
    ],
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/typescript-node:20
```

```
$ devcontainer build .
[12 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.35.0. Node.js v16.14.2. linux 5.15.0-41-generic x64.
[519 ms] Start: Run: docker buildx build --load --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 -f /tmp/devcontainercli-craig/container-features/0.35.0-1682146167065/Dockerfile-with-features -t vsc-testdevc-badaeb5eab5ce3c45f2eb0d49d69644c94fb162ab4a701e8569eeb7219cdbf07 --target dev_containers_target_stage --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=dev_container_auto_added_stage_label /home/craig/testDevc/.devcontainer
[+] Building 0.1s (6/6) FINISHED                                                
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-with-features         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.38kB                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/typescri  0.1s
 => CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 1/1] FROM mcr.microsoft.  0.0s
 => preparing layers for inline cache                                      0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                     0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                    0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:0fa55cc0ebea427319bfb7cb68823433bc84e04ebb016  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/vsc-testdevc-badaeb5eab5ce3c45f2eb0d49  0.0s
{"outcome":"success","imageName":["vsc-testdevc-badaeb5eab5ce3c45f2eb0d49d69644c94fb162ab4a701e8569eeb7219cdbf07"]}
```

```
$ devcontainer open
[229 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.35.0. Node.js v16.14.2. linux 5.15.0-41-generic x64.
```

From the vscode terminal inside the container

```
node ➜ /workspaces/testDevc $ ls -al
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 22 06:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 22 06:49 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 22 06:49 .devcontainer
node ➜ /workspaces/testDevc $ ls -an
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 0 0 4096 Apr 22 07:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 0 0 4096 Apr 22 06:49 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 0 0 4096 Apr 22 06:49 .devcontainer
node ➜ /workspaces/testDevc $ whoami
node
node ➜ /workspaces/testDevc $ id
uid=1000(node) gid=1000(node) groups=1000(node),998(nvm),999(npm)
node ➜ /workspaces/testDevc $ groups
node nvm npm
node ➜ /workspaces/testDevc $ cat > test.txt
bash: test.txt: Permission denied
node ➜ /workspaces/testDevc $
```

From a terminal outside the container:

```
craig@desk:0:~/testDevc$ ls -al
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  3 craig craig 4096 Apr 22 00:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 55 craig craig 4096 Apr 21 23:48 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 craig craig 4096 Apr 21 23:49 .devcontainer
craig@desk:0:~/testDevc$ whoami
craig
craig@desk:0:~/testDevc$ id
uid=1000(craig) gid=1000(craig) groups=1000(craig),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),120(lpadmin),131(lxd),132(sambashare),255(common),998(docker),1001(craig1001)
craig@desk:0:~/testDevc$ cat > test2.txt
hello
craig@desk:0:~/testDevc$ cat test2.txt
hello
```

As you can see, user `craig` on the host and user `node` on the container share the same uid.  I though that was enough to ensure that `node` would be able to write files.

What am I missing?  Could it be because the host is ubuntu linux and not a WSL?

Comment: Do you need this complexity?  If you're on an Ubuntu host, can you `sudo apt-get install nodejs` to get a Node interpreter, without involving Docker at all?

Comment: @DavidMaze - Actually I am trying to run vsode in a container, for security reasons.  vscode has associated software `devcountainer`, and an associated vscode extension, and I was originally trying to run that when the same permissions problem occurred.  `devcontainer` is built on top on docker.  Devcontainer allows vscode to be run on in a container environment.  So I am making the above described attempt in docker to find out what the basic problem is.  At least I already know it not just a problem with `devcontainer`, but rather an issue with docker - so that's a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0. Summary

   This explains how to enable both the `devcontainer`-created container and the host to both be able to write files on the same mounted directory.

   1 - In the container configuration, the Dockerfile is modified so the group write permission flags will be set on write.

   2 - On the host side, first a new group is created which matches the container group, and the host user is added to that group.

   3 - Then, the development directores and files permission flags are set.
1. Dockerfile

   Add this line to .devcountainer/Dockerfile:

   `RUN su node -c "echo 'umask 0002' >> /home/node/.bashrc"`

   For example, this a working .devcountainer/Dockerfile:

   ```
   ARG VARIANT=20-bullseye
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/javascript-node:0-${VARIANT}
   RUN su node -c "echo 'umask 0002' >> /home/node/.bashrc"
   ```
2. Add group on host

   In the case of ubuntu 20 host, the uid of files owned by the user on the container are observed to be 100999. This will likely vary by system.

   On the host create a group with gid 100999, and add the host user to that group. It is necessary to log out and log back in again for it to take effect.

   ```
   sudo addgroup --gid 100999 g100999
   sudo usermod -a -G g100999 craig
   ```
3. Set host development directory permissions

   ```
   sudo find . -type d -exec chmod g+rwxs {} +
   sudo find . -type f -exec chmod g+rw {} +
   ```

---

Edit: added this to step 3:

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod g+t {}  +
```

This removes the "sticky bit" which prevents file deletion from the host side. (This "stick bit" doesn't interfere with writing, only with deletion, and it applies to parent directory of hte file, not the file itself).

Comment: i do something similar. it works for if you create files using a terminal windows..the files are group read/writeable. but not if you are creating the file say using visual studio code.

Comment: @mike01010 - Right, so that why I added steps 2 and 3.  I run `git` from outside of VS, as well as making frequent use of `meld` via `git diftool`.  So I need to be able R/W from both inside and outside the container.  By running `git` from outside the container, I never have to expose keys to inside VS code (the keys for github).

Comment: thanks.  My use case is slightly diff in that we have multiple devs on the same linux host running their own instance of the dev container.  There are files that are created by team members using vscode or the by running the code in vscode that is written to a mounted share.  Its problematic because we can edit those files collaboratively..

Comment: @mike01010 - Can I ask why you don't use `git` (or some other version control software) to avoid the problems of sharing a single copy?

Comment: this arent' source code...they are data file and other such file. sometimes the files  created we modify at the target location to test different types of scenarios. or if one dev is having issues another might want to tweak that file and try it in his environment - that dev cant right now without copying the contents to another file they create.  sometimes its just a lot quicker to make those mods without some process on around it for testing/debugging...